# Why does $(2^x -1)/x$ not have a vertical asymptote?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, asymptotics

Why does $(2^x -1)/x$ not have a vertical asymptote as opposed to $(2^x)/x$?

Can you factor in the first expression so that you can cancel out the $x$ term?

Comment: for $x $ near zero, $$ 2^x  \approx  1 + x \log 2 + \frac{x^2 \log^2 2}{2} $$ so $$ 2^x - 1  \approx   x \log 2 + \frac{x^2 \log^2 2}{2} $$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... It's worth noting that, while the function doesn't have an *asymptote* at $x=0$, it *does* have a "hole" there, which may not appear in computer-generated plots. (That said, the hole is a "removable discontinuity", so context may consider the hole filled.) In any case ... Some context would be helpful. Eg, having tagged this question with `calculus`, are you familiar with limits, indeterminate forms, or perhaps even power series? Such information can help people avoid explaining things you already understand, or using techniques beyond your current level. Cheers!

Comment: This is why we say "$0/0$ is an indeterminate form".  Your calculus text should discuss that topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really wonderful question!

For small values of $x$, $2^x$ is approximately equal to $1 + (\ln 2)x$.  This is not obvious (unless you know Calculus), but if you graph both functions and zoom in you will see that their graphs are indistinguishable near $x = 0$.

So for small values of $x$,
$$\frac{2^x - 1}{x} \approx \frac {1 + (\ln 2)x - 1}{x} = \ln 2$$

Answer (score 1):

mweiss gave already a nice explanation, but let me give a proof requiring as little calculus as I can.

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb R$ be $f(x) = (2^x-1)/x$.
For function $f$ to have vertical asymptote at $x = 0$ it would have to be unbounded near $0$. Our function is not defined at $0$, but there exists limit: $$
\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{2^x - 2^0}{x - 0} = \left. (2^x)' \right|_{x=0} = \left. (\ln 2\cdot 2^x) \right|_{x=0} =\ln 2.
$$
Let's define $\tilde f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as $$
\tilde f(x) =\begin{cases}
          f(x) \quad &\text{if} \, x \neq 0 \\
          \ln 2\quad &\text{if} \, x = 0. \\
     \end{cases}
$$
Since $f$ was continuous on its domain, and $\tilde f$ is continuous at $x = 0$, then $\tilde f$ is continuous everywhere. So in particular, it is bounded near $0$ (formally, using Extreme Value Theorem it is bounded on for example $[-1, 1]$). That shows $f$ is bounded near $0$.        $\square$